# Computing array values based on their index using Julia Broadcasting in julia

Tags: julia, array-broadcasting

I want to compute an array such that `a[i,1] = (l*i)/k` where `l` and `k` are constant scalar values and `i` is the row number. **Obvious solution would be to loop through all the `i` values and add the values**, but I want to use ***Julia Broadcasting*** on this and I cannot find any documentation on this.

EDIT: `a` is a two-dimensional array of zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializing:

```
jl> a = zeros(5, 2);

jl> k, l = 3, 2π;
```

You have several choices here. For ordinary arrays, this will work:

```
jl> a[:, 1] .= l .* (1:size(a, 1)) ./ k
5-element view(::Matrix{Float64}, :, 1) with eltype Float64:
  2.0943951023931953
  4.1887902047863905
  6.283185307179586
  8.377580409572783
 10.471975511965978
```

This one is more general, and actually preferable in my view:

```
jl> a[:, 1] .= l .* axes(a, 1) ./ k
```

For a little more context on `axes(a, n)`, it is a generic way to get the indices of any (or all) dimensions of an array. `axes(a, 1)` returns `Base.OneTo(5)`, which, if you `collect` it (don't do that, btw) is

```
jl> collect(axes(a, 1))
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Without a dimension argument you get all dimensions, two in this case:

```
jl> axes(a)
(Base.OneTo(5), Base.OneTo(2))
```

`axes` is preferable to `1:size(a, 1)` because it also works for arrays with zero-based or other kinds of indices.

Comment: How does computationally compare `axes()` to `1:size()` ?

Comment: Should be no difference. For ordinary arrays, `axes` returns a range nearly equivalent to `1:size`. It is theoretically possible that `axes(a, 1)` is slightly faster, since it contains information about its starting value in the type domain, but in practice it's not noticeable.